# jQuery drag and drop then open alert specific for each list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem with jQuery. I have 3 unordered lists and I want when list item is dropped from first ul to second or third to open an alert with information different for every list item. Here is what I've made but it is not working: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zLdgyLg/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('ul.connectedSortable').sortable({
    connectWith: "#sortable2, #sortable3",
    helper: 'clone',
    stop: function (event, ui) {
      var itemTypeID = ui.draggable.attr("id");
      var itemType = itemTypeID.data("draggableItem");
      switch (itemType) { 
        case 'text': 
          alert('text!');
          break;
        case 'photo': 
          alert('photo!');
          break;
        case 'video': 
          alert('video!');
          break;        
        case 'music': 
          alert('music!');
          break;
        default:
          alert(itemType);
      }
    }
  });

  $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable2, #sortable3",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
});
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with the code. jQueryUI could be a hard to understand, I suffered it.

- First of all, you don't need to declare li as draggable (if there is no other functionality behind) cause sortable do the thing for you.
- `ui.item` it's already a jQuery item to ask for `.data()` You retrieve the id, but that is just text, on your approach you should wrap it up with `$('#'+itemTypeID)` but jQueryUI already did that for you.

I tried this and I think it's what you're trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('ul.connectedSortable').sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    helper: 'clone',
    stop: function (event, ui) {
      var itemType = ui.item.data("draggableitem");
      switch (itemType) { 
        case 'text': 
          alert('text!');
          break;
        case 'photo': 
          alert('photo!');
          break;
        case 'video': 
          alert('video!');
          break;        
        case 'music': 
          alert('music!');
          break;
        default:
          alert(itemType);
      }
    }
  });
});
```